# How can I align a text block with a header?

Tags: spacing, indentation

I created this .tex document

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{-37pt}{0pt}{10pt}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{-16pt}{0pt}{0pt}

1) header h1
   A. Subheader h3
      textblock

   B. Subheader h3
      textblock

2) header h1
      textblock h1
```

I want to move `textblock h1` aligned under `2) header h1`:

```
2) header h1
   textblock h1
```

How can I do this?
Can I do this with `\titlespacing`?
It seems to me that you can only move headers with `\titlespacing`
Are there other packages to obtain this output?

Comment: Hi Reman, can you please add a complete MWE illustrating the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question. Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}

% based on the code in `texdoc titlesec`, sec. 9.2
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}
  {1em}{}
  [\global\leftskip-10pt\relax]
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}
  {1em}{}
  [\global\leftskip0pt\relax]

\titlespacing{\section}{-37pt}{0pt}{10pt}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{-16pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section{title}
\subsection{title}
\lipsum[1]

\section{title}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]